# C++: How to make comparison function for char arrays?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is this possible? i get weird error message when i put char as the type:

```
inline bool operator==(const char *str1, const char *str2){
    // ...
}
```

Error message: `error C2803: 'operator ==' must have at least one formal parameter of class type` ... which i dont understand at all.

I was thinking if i could directly compare stuff like:

```
const char *str1 = "something";
const char *str2 = "something else";
const char str3[] = "lol"; // not sure if this is same as above
```

and then compare:

```
if(str1 == str2){
   // ...
}
```

etc.

But i also want it to work with:

```
char *str = new char[100];
```

and:

```
char *str = (char *)malloc(100);
```

I am assuming every char array i use this way would end in NULL character, so the checking should be possible, but i understand it can be unsafe etc. I just want to know if this is possible to do, and how.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the string functions in <string>, strncmp, strnlen, strncat, etc?

Comment: @pstrjds: Actually, these are in `<cstring>`, `<string>` houses the `std::basic_string<>` template and the `std::string` typedef.

Comment: good call, my bad, I actually provided a link to cstring in my answer, just was typing hastily :)

Comment: i know strings, already use them, but i just wanted to clear my head from the error message. now it makes sense, thanks to all!

Comment: *> Is there any reason why you can't use the string functions*   How about templates? You can’t write a generic function if some types *require* specialized comparisons, at least not without specializing. If you could overload the equality operator, the generic template would work for all types so long as an `operator==()` exists.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible. As your compiler points out, you cannot overload this operator for primitive data types. At least one side of the comparison must be non-primitive for the overload to be possible.

In the same sense, you cannot derive a new class from a primitive data type (to add functionality to it).

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense, then i would overwrite the original comparison functions, lol stupid me...

Comment: See also: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/intrinsics-and-operator-overloading.html

Answer (score 4):

You are attempting to compare two pointers.

```
const char* str1 = "string1";
const char* str2 = "string1";

if(str1 == str2) // never true, str1 is not the same pointer as str2
{
};
```

But, you've provided the C++ tag, so you should be using `std::string`:

```
#include <string>

std::string str1 = "string1";
std::string str2 = "string1";

if(str1 == str2)  // yes!  std::string overloads operator ==
{
}
```

Comment: He asked specifically about overloading operators.

Comment: I'd rather take your hasty down-vote than support operator overloading of `==` with two `const char*` when there are perfectly good classes and operations available.  This is C++.

Comment: The comparison of the two pointers in the fist snippet may or may not return true. Both pointers point to string literals with the same content and the compiler is allowed to merge those string literals. However, this should not depended on and definitely won't work with anything else than string literals.

Comment: @etarion:  Just because he asked specifically about operator overloading doesn't mean he *should* be overloading operators.  One of SO's strengths is when someone is doing the *wrong thing*, we don't just tell them how to do the wrong thing, we tell them what the right thing is.

Comment: @John Dibling,Moo-Juice: The answer would have been fine if it had explained where the error message he got and didn't understand came from. Dodging the error without understanding it is not a way to learn.

Comment: Yeah, i just wanted to know the reason why its making error, but i didnt think deep enough... im already using strings, just interested on how strings work internally etc.

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are built-in types. There are built-in comparison operators for them already, you cannot override them. Just use `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

You most certainly, totally can write your own comparison function, and in fact it's one of the most basic things to do.  I have no idea why someone would say that you can't.  You just can't call it `operator =`.  Here it is (untested):

```
int my_strcmp(char const* s1, char const* s2)
{
  for(;*s1 == *s2 && *s1; ++s1,++s2);

  return *s1 - *s2;
}

...
if (!my_strcmp(str1, str2)) // they're ==.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `strcmp()` to compare chars:  It works on char pointers `char *`  and char arrays `char [ ]` .

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *string_Char_pointer1 = {"2012-12-06 14:28:51"};
char *string_Char_pointer2 = {"1911-12-06 14:28:51"};

char string_Char_Array1[] = "2012-12-06 14:28:51";
char string_Char_Array2[] = "1911-12-06 14:28:51";

int main( void )
{
   char tmp[20];
   int result;

   printf( "Comparing  string_Char_pointer..\n\n\n");

   printf( "Compared strings:\n   %s\n   %s\n\n\n", string_Char_pointer1, string_Char_pointer2 );
   result = strcmp( string_Char_pointer1, string_Char_pointer2 );

   if( result > 0 )        strcpy( tmp, "greater than" );
   else if( result < 0 )   strcpy( tmp, "less than" );
   else    strcpy( tmp, "equal to" );

   printf( "   strcmp:   String 1 is %s string 2\n\n", tmp );

   printf( "\n\nComparing string_Char_Array..\n\n");

   printf( "Compared strings:\n   %s\n   %s\n\n\n", string_Char_Array1, string_Char_Array2 );
   result = strcmp( string_Char_pointer1, string_Char_pointer2 );

   if( result > 0 )        strcpy( tmp, "greater than" );
   else if( result < 0 )   strcpy( tmp, "less than" );
   else    strcpy( tmp, "equal to" );




   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Decided that my comment would be better as an answer, you should use the standard [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/) functions for this (strncmp, strncat, etc).

Edit:
As pointed out in another answer, you can't do the overload. But in the case of the char arrays and char pointers you should use the standard library functions.